# Search function not clearing

Tags: jquery, search

I have this search function which highlights input text and I would like to clear the input value on another button click. I have tried multiple functions including

```
$('#searchInput').val("");
```

The above clears the input field but not the text being highlighted in the DOM. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup change", function(e) {
    var text = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (text !== "" && text !== " ") {
      var pattern = new RegExp(text, "gi");
    } else {
      $(".accordian-holder").removeClass("displayNone");
      $(".accordian-holder")
        .children("article")
        .removeClass("displayNone");
    }
    $(".searchtext, .searchtabsheading").each(function(i) {
      var str = this;
      var orgText = $(str).text();
      orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1) {
        return (
          "<span style='color: rgb(53, 53, 53); background: rgb(255, 255, 255);'>" +
          $1 +
          "</span>"
        );
      });
      $(str).html(orgText);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try like this `$(#searchInput).val();`

Comment: @Husna that's the getter not the setter.

Comment: @Liam given the OP states that line of code works I'm going to assume that's just a basic typo in the question and that the underlying issue of clearing the highlight is the issue which needs addressing.

Comment: you will also be used `$("#searchInput").reset();`

Comment: @Husna again, that's incorrect. jQuery has no `reset()` method. All that will do is give you an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to put a `class` on the `span` you append. Then you can select than `span` when you want to clear the highlighting and just `unwrap()` its contents. Try this:

```js
$("#searchInput").on("keyup change", function(e) {
  var text = $.trim($(this).val());
  if (text !== "" && text !== " ") {
    var pattern = new RegExp(text, "gi");
  } else {
    $(".accordian-holder, .accordian-holder article").removeClass("displayNone");
  }
  
  $(".searchtext, .searchtabsheading").each(function(i) {
    var str = this;
    var orgText = $(str).text();
    orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1) {
      return '<span class="highlight">' + $1 + '</span>'
    });
    $(str).html(orgText);
  });
});

$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#searchInput').val('');
  $('.highlight').contents().unwrap();
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: #C00;
  background-color: #CC0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchInput"  />
<button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
<div class="searchtext">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Note that I amended the colours of the highlight for this example only as they weren't visible in the snippet editor.